# Linux tool to automatically grab and store URLs from clipboard

Tags: linux, automation, bookmark, clipboard

**I'm looking for a tool that periodically reads the content of my clipboard, scans it for any links/URLs found and saves those as some kind of bookmarks.**

I often need to extract and store multiple URLs from longer texts. The best workflow for me would be just to copy those texts into the clipboard and have a tool that watches the clipboard for changes and than extracts all the URLs it can find.

Currently, I'm using `jddownloader` for that task, but this is clunky, slow and way overkill to just grab and store some links. So I'm looking for a more lightweight alternative.

I'm currently running debian with xfce 4.18

Answer (score 0):

[CopyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) will definitely do what you want.

You can configure it to watch the clipboard and then act on any URLs that are copied to it.  You will have to write a short script to get it to do exactly what you want, but if you have coding experience, it will be easy.

What makes CopyQ even more powerful is that, if you desire, you can specify to act only on clipboard items copied from specific applications or even specific windows from within specific applications!  This can be incredibly powerful with a little imagination.

CopyQ is completely open-source and is cross-platform for Linux, macOS, and Windows.  As of this writing, it is actively developed.  The primary developer is the talented Lukas Holecek.